# How to get random object from array in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Im trying to get a random object from an array, and add it to a string.

```
var input = ['1', '2', '3']
    console.log(input[Math.floor(Math.random() * input.length)] + " some text")
```

However, when you run this, it does nothing. If you label this post as a duplicate, please know that the question is not asking how to randomize an array, my question is how do I add an object from an array, and add it to a string.

Comment: Elaborate on "it does nothing." It works fine.

Comment: @zhuravlyov, you just assigned `input.length` to a variable. It works either ways.

Comment: Correctly. His code works fine, I just post s JS snippet to show him that his code works.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to add a string from array instead of object. And your code works fine, try this.

```js
"use strict";

let input = ['1', '2', '3'];
let amount = input.length;

console.log(input[Math.floor(Math.random() * amount)] + " some text");
```